# How to avoid popup of images in Google reCAPTCHA in Java Web Application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, recaptcha

I have integrated Google reCAPTCHA in Java Web Application,on click of check box image popup appears.But according to my requirement it sholud not appear.Can i avoid images popup.If it so how could i do it.

Any suggestion and help is appreciated.